# setfill() and setw() Java equivalent?

Tags: java, string, padding

I have an assignment where we are required to create a User class with a toString() method. The toString method should return a string with all the information about the user. We are required to create an array of 50 User objects and print the information about each user on a separate line. The problem is, I want to keep everything in a neat table with all Strings of the same length. So for instance:

```
User Name          Password          Full Name                     Email
___________________________________________________________________________________________
shortUser          12345             John Smith                    jSmith@shortnames.com
thisUserIsLonger   1234567890        Smitty Werbenjagermanjensen   Smitty@thisOneIsLong.com
```

I would like to keep everything aligned as it is in the above table. This would be easy in C++ since I could just use setw() to dynamically pad spaces between according to the size of the field. Is something like this possible in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this may not be the exact thing you are looking for, but if you were comfortable with printf and its siblings, take a look at the [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

There are many was to store the data and retrieve as you prefered
eg : store in DBMS or serialize the data

As there is not much data I would stick to serialization.

1. First you need to create person been class.

   ```
   class Person{
   String name;
   String pwd;
   String email;
   String fullName;

   // make the getters and setters

   }
   ```
2. Set `Person` data using setters (you may use a loop)
3. Add the object person to a ArrayList

   ```
   arrayListObj.add(person1);
   ```
4. [serialize the ArrayList](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0075.html)

   try {
         System.out.println("serializing list");
         FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("list.dat");
         ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
         oos.writeObject(arrayListObj);
         oos.close();
     }
     catch (Exception e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
     }
5. Deserialize as follows

   ```
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("list.dat");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        List<String> list = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();

        for (String s : list){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        ois.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
   ```
6. After deserializing you may have to use [iterator](http://www.java-examples.com/iterate-through-elements-java-arraylist-using-iterator-example) to invoke the list

These are the basic steps that you could follow to achieve your target!

After words it is just about the print the result.